# How to access files uploaded by Media Plugin?

Tags: cakephp

Simple question. I've been trying to do that, but can't! I uploaded an image and it's stored in app/webroot/media/transfer/img/hawk.png

How can access it? Tried searching here on Stack Overflow and the CakePHP discussion group but didn't find anything. I supposed this is a simple question, but it's killing me since I can't answer it. :(

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`src="media/transfer/img/hawk.png"` I thought should work because of the webroot acting as root of directory? have you tried that?

Comment: I did: echo $this->Html->image('media/transfer/img/hawk.png');
And the output: <img src="/gp2/img/media/transfer/img/hawk.png" alt="">

Answer (score 0):

How about this: `echo $this->Html->image('../media/transfer/img/hawk.png');`

Comment: Because this is the pattern for the Media Plugin. I thought since they decided this, it would be easy to get the file from it. :(

Comment: I just edited my answer 20min ago. And if it's not working, what's the generated img tag?

Comment: <img src="/gp2/img/../media/transfer/img/hawk.png" alt="">

Comment: gp2 being the folder of my project

Comment: so where's your app/webroot folder located? It's simply a matter of going back to the first common directory and refer the image from there.

Comment: Is located in the root folder of my server. So if I was to acces my app, it would be http://localhost:8888/gp2/